# How to show hide dynamic parse divs?

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I have a form with a select menu with the values 1,2,3,4. When 3 is selected 3 sub div's are visible, but with 1 select just 1 is visible.

I created some simple span div which holds the input fields per user

```
<span id="ticketuser1">....</span><span id="ticketuser2">....etc

$('#numOfTickets').change(function() {
                var num= $("#numOfTickets").val();

                for (var i=0;i<num;i++){ 
                    if(i>num){
                        $('#ticketuser'+i).hide();
                    } else {
                        $('#ticketuser'+i).show();
                    }
                }

        });
```

Now from 2 to 3 to 4 goes as expected but selecting a lower number doesn't do the trick.

Any tips?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle to help explain the problem?

Comment: @alex show the complete form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your loop is never getting to the hide condition because the hide condition is also the end condition.

```
$('#numOfTickets').change(function() {
        var num= $("#numOfTickets").val();

        for (var i=0;i<num;i++){ 
            if(i>num){
                $('#ticketuser'+i).hide();
            } else {
                $('#ticketuser'+i).show();
            }
        }

});
```

You need to have two loops and a variable that can either be static or dynamic.

In my simple example I chose to make it static:

```
var maxUser = 5;

$(function () {
    $('#numOfTickets').change(function () {
        var num = parseInt($(this).val())+1;
        for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
            $('#ticketUser' + i).show();            
        }    
        for (var j = num ; j <= maxUser; j++){
            $('#ticketUser' + j).hide();            
        }                                
    });
});
```

So if the div is less than the `maxUser` but greater than `num`, it is shown.

In the second loop we hide everything over `num`.

`num` is your value +1 so that your loop will grab the last item you intend to show.

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELpuV/)
If you want the variable to be dynamic and based on the options available as the page loads, [then here is another example](http://jsfiddle.net/ELpuV/1/). You could easily add the code from load that initializes the `maxUser` variable in the second example and place it in the change function if the options were dynamic.